# How to remove/delete a list of Entry<K,V> from a map?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have below scenario:

A `LinkedHashMap` ordered map contains thousands of  `<k,V>`.
I have created a `List<Entry<K,V>>`. I am processing 1000 `Entry<K,V>` at a time by using sublist method of List.

Issue what I am facing is, even we have used a portion of map (i.e. sublist of `List<Entry<K,V>>`) I have not removed that from map. This is using a lot of memory in heap.

Can any one suggest me here how I can get rid of used data from `LinkedHashMap` (this is ordered map) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map.entries().removeAll(listOfEntries);
```

should remove all entries matching an element of the list from the map.